# Question in Proof of Gelfand's Formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Gelfand's formula states that the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ satisfies
$$\rho(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert A^n \Vert ^{1/n}.$$
Multiple proofs of Gelfand's formula (including [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand%27s_formula) one on Wikipedia) have a step, stating if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} A^n = 0,$$
where $0$ refers to the all-zeros matrix, then there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have
$$ \Vert A^n \Vert < 1,$$
for any matrix norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$.

Since this is true for any matrix norm, it should follow from the axioms of matrix norm. However, I am having difficulty justifying this step, and would appreciate a proof for that claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norm is continuous, so if for some sequence of linear operators $T_n$, $\lim_n T_n=0$, the zero operator, then $\lim_n ||T_n||=||0||=0$, the scalar.

Comment: I may be missing something simple here in your argument. If $lim_n T_n = 0$ is the same normed space, then by subadditivity/continuity of norm the above follows. But I am unsure how that argument works when $$lim_n T_n = 0$ elementwise. I apolologize in advance if this is trivial.

Comment: @kruillli, ah... this is perhaps a significant detail. What do you mean "elementwise"? Do you mean something like the "strong topology", given by seminorms $\nu_x(T)=|Tx|$ for $x$ in the vector space? The formulation of your question strongly suggests that you're talking about the operator-norm topology... Clarify?

Comment: @kruillli, ah, yes, then, you are apparently using the so-called _weak_ topology, given by semi-norms $\nu_{x,y}(T)=|\langle Tx,y\rangle|$, where $x,y$ are in the vector space. This creates complications. I don't think this is what one wants to understand Gelfand's formula... for infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. Yes, for finite-dimensional spaces all topologies on operators are the same, etc. But some convenient version for f.d. spaces do not extend well to infinite-dimensional. Clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using the result $\rho(T) <1$ iff $lim_n T^n = 0$ as stated and proved [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence). The proof involves finding the Jordan decomposition, and observing that each entry in the jordan decomposition n-th power approaches 0 as $n$ goes to infinity. Specifically, the entry in row $i$ and column $j$ of $T^n$ denoted $(T^n)_{i,j}$ satisfies
$$ lim_n (T^n)_{i,j} = 0$$
for all rows $i$ and columns $j$.

Comment: Yes, this is a version of the weak operator topology. I'm not confident that Gelfand's formula is correct for this notion of "goes to $0$". Also, I do suspect that you do not really need or want this, although if it did succeed, it might be convenient.

Comment: I see. Then I feel like I am misunderstanding [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence) statement or its usage in the proof of Gelfand provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Gelfand's_formula).

Comment: Both those arguments should surely use the ("uniform") operator norm, not any sort of element-wise norm. Possibly Wiki's arguments have some flaws...

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your help. I saw a similar argument from this [source](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/giron/teaching/linalg/gelfand.pdf), which makes me think I am missing something, or the sources may be omitting some details.